# Como dar um comando EXECUTE IMMEDIATE em um banco ORACLE partindo de uma aplicação JAVA?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, oracle

O erro é quando executo:

```
execute immediate 'update teste set num = 1234 where num = 1';
```

Exceção:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: instrução SQL inválida
```

Comment: Olá @lucasRomero, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Em qual contexto você está tentando realizar este comando? Se é via aplicação não bastaria um update? Se não me falhe a memória, o `execute immediate` é para ser utilizado dentro de triggers e funções

Comment: Essa linha que eu postei é apenas de teste, as que serão executadas eu não tenho acesso.

Comment: Renan, a parte do comando `update teste set num = 1234 where num = 1` está beleza, já testei select, insert, update e delete. Porém não executei testes com o `execute immediate`.

Comment: Removi meu comentário anterior porque realmente estava errado [de acordo com o manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm). A coluna `num` é realmente numérica?

Comment: É numérica. Se eu executar apenas `update teste set num = 1234 where num = 1` dá certo, o problema é quando eu acrescento `excute immediate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve utilizar somente o comando de update

```
update teste set num = 1234 where num = 1
```

O EXECUTE IMMEDIATE é somente para executar sentenças SQL dentro de blocos de funções ou triggers PL/SQL *[(vide documentação)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm)*